# Can't stream audio from OSX Mavericks to Apple TV

Tags: macos, audio, airplay

Lately, when I click in "Apple TV" (trying to select it as default sound output), OSX changes it back to "Internal Speakers".

[image: sound settings]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

much simpler command:

```
sudo pkill coreaudiod
```

Answer (score 4):

Just had this problem myself, and this solution worked for me:
Open a terminal and kill the audio driver, it will restart and everything should work straight away.

```
sudo kill `ps -ax | grep 'coreaudiod' | grep 'sbin' |awk '{print $1}'`
```

Comment: Would you know how to create a scriptfile with this command, and also how to supply my password in the command? It ask for my password when using it in terminal. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

`sudo killall coreaudiod` is easier.

Answer (score 0):

Disable and enable wifi.

This avoids killing coreaudiod.